# Why video tag can know the duration of video?

Tags: html, html5-video

I see the request header included

> Range:bytes=4096000-

when I clicked to play the video first time.

However, the html video tag is how to know the duration of whole video when it just downloaded the partial content?

Secondly, how the video tag convert the byte range to exact timestamp in video?